# run gnome-terminal with executable command

Tags: gnome-terminal

When i run gnome-terminal with the -e to execute a command  the PATH used to find the command is not the PATH used in the terminal initiating the command

For example:

I open an terminal and set the PATH to be "./:$PATH

type in `gnome-terminal -e cluster_node`

It can't find the cluster node.
if I `type gnome-terminal -e ./cluster_node` it works

If I add in the /etc/environment the PATH ./ then it works always/

I think it doesn't use the terminal environment PATH from which it was launched.

Comment: You have to export your $PATH. At any rate, it is better to install your /luster_node in a standard location ( /usr/local/ ) or add the proper (full) path to your $PATH as "./" is ambiguous .

Answer (score 2):

For a new variable, you can export it, such as:

```
> export NEWVAR=something
```

However as in this case, the PATH variable is set by the shell's initialization scripts (/etc/profile, ~/.bashrc, etc).  Changes to PATH in the parent shell are blown away by those initialization scripts in the child shell.  Options you have:

1. Ensure whatever you are trying to run is in a well-known location (/usr/local/bin, etc)
2. Ensure you specify the full path when you run gnome-terminal
3. Reset the variable as part of the execution:

> gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'export PATH=$PATH:/.; whatever.sh'